# No consigo encontrar la formula de xpath para suma de un ejercicio que me mandaron

Tags: xml, xpath

La pregunta sobre un `xml` es Suma de Goyas que han ganado las películas del género comedia:

```
sum(//peliculas/pelicula[genero="Comedia"])
```

Número de películas de género comedia, ¿sera count o sum?

```
<PremiosGoya>
  <!--Peliculas y directores de las peliculas ganadoras del Goya a la Mejor Película desde el año 2001-->
  <!--Peliculas ganadoras Goya Mejor película-->
  <peliculas>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P01" fecha="2001">
      <titulo>Los otros</titulo>
      <genero>Suspense</genero>
      <numGoyas>8</numGoyas>
      <director>D01</director>
      <!--Codigo del director, hace referencia a <director codDirector="">-->
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P02" fecha="2002">
      <titulo>Los lunes al sol</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>5</numGoyas>
      <director>D02</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P03" fecha="2003">
      <titulo>Te doy mis ojos</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>7</numGoyas>
      <director>D03</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P04" fecha="2004">
      <titulo>Mar adentro</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>14</numGoyas>
      <director>D01</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P05" fecha="2005">
      <titulo>La vida secreta de las palabras</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>4</numGoyas>
      <director>D04</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P06" fecha="2006">
      <titulo>Volver</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>5</numGoyas>
      <director>D05</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P07" fecha="2007">
      <titulo>La soledad</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>3</numGoyas>
      <director>D06</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P08" fecha="2008">
      <titulo>Camino</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>6</numGoyas>
      <director>D07</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P09" fecha="2009">
      <titulo>Celda 211</titulo>
      <genero>Thriller</genero>
      <numGoyas>9</numGoyas>
      <director>D08</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P10" fecha="2010">
      <titulo>Pa negre</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>6</numGoyas>
      <director>D09</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P11" fecha="2011">
      <titulo>No habrá paz para los malvados</titulo>
      <genero>Thriller</genero>
      <numGoyas>6</numGoyas>
      <director>D10</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P12" fecha="2012">
      <titulo>Blancanieves</titulo>
      <genero>Fantasía</genero>
      <numGoyas>11</numGoyas>
      <director>D11</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P13" fecha="2013">
      <titulo>Vivir es fácil con los ojos cerrados</titulo>
      <genero>Comedia</genero>
      <numGoyas>6</numGoyas>
      <director>D12</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P14" fecha="2014">
      <titulo>La isla mínima</titulo>
      <genero>Thriller</genero>
      <numGoyas>10</numGoyas>
      <director>D13</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P15" fecha="2015">
      <titulo>Truman</titulo>
      <genero>Comedia</genero>
      <numGoyas>5</numGoyas>
      <director>D14</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P16" fecha="2016">
      <titulo>Tarde para la ira</titulo>
      <genero>Thriller</genero>
      <numGoyas>4</numGoyas>
      <director>D15</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P17" fecha="2017">
      <titulo>La librería</titulo>
      <genero>Drama</genero>
      <numGoyas>3</numGoyas>
      <director>D04</director>
    </pelicula>
    <pelicula idPelicula="P18" fecha="2018">
      <titulo>Campeones</titulo>
      <genero>Comedia</genero>
      <numGoyas>3</numGoyas>
      <director>D07</director>
    </pelicula>
  </peliculas>
  <!--Directores con Goya a la Mejor Película-->
  <directores>
    <director codDirector="D01">
      <nombre>Alejandro</nombre>
      <apellidos>Amenábar</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D02">
      <nombre>Fernando</nombre>
      <apellidos>León de Aranoa</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D03">
      <nombre>Icíar</nombre>
      <apellidos>Bollaín</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D04">
      <nombre>Isabel</nombre>
      <apellidos>Coixet</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D05">
      <nombre>Pedro</nombre>
      <apellidos>Almodovar</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D06">
      <nombre>Jaime</nombre>
      <apellidos>Rosales</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D07">
      <nombre>Javier</nombre>
      <apellidos>Fesser</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D08">
      <nombre>Daniel</nombre>
      <apellidos>Monzón</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D09">
      <nombre>Agustí</nombre>
      <apellidos>Villaronga</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D10">
      <nombre>Enrique</nombre>
      <apellidos>Urbizu</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D11">
      <nombre>Pablo</nombre>
      <apellidos>Berger</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D12">
      <nombre>David</nombre>
      <apellidos>Trueba</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D13">
      <nombre>Alberto</nombre>
      <apellidos>Rodriguez</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D14">
      <nombre>Cesc</nombre>
      <apellidos>Gay</apellidos>
    </director>
    <director codDirector="D15">
      <nombre>Raúl</nombre>
      <apellidos>Arévalo</apellidos>
    </director>
  </directores>
</PremiosGoya>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que sumar el contenido del elemento, no el elemento, por eso necesitas acceder al mismo con `text()`, por ejemplo para saber todos los goyas que se han entregado te bastaría con esta línea:

```
sum(//peliculas/pelicula/numGoyas/text())
```

Si quieres saber los de comedia, entonces tendrás que añadir una condición, porque género es hermano de goya, e hijo de película.

```
sum(//peliculas/pelicula/numGoyas/text() and //peliculas/pelicula[genero="Comedia"])
```